# My problem is with linked list in Java? How can I use the elements (rabat) from linked list to achieve average price?

Tags: java

I am a beginner and I want code a easy program which will be use LinkedList and which give me average of rabat price. Can I use LinkedList in this way?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public  class Apartment {
    private  String city;
    private double area;
    private double price;
    private float multiplier = 0.95f;
    private double rabat;
    private static int number = 1;
    private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    Apartment(String city, double area, double price) {
        this.city = city;
        this.area = area;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public  void getFullPrice() {
        rabat = price * multiplier;
        System.out.println(number++ + " : Apartment in  " + city + " cost " + df2.format(rabat));
    }

    public  double average () {
        System.out.println(rabat);
        return rabat;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apartment honkong = new Apartment (" Hongkong ",15.00,8000.12);
        Apartment kraków = new Apartment (" Krakow ",15.00,250.12);
        Apartment warszawa = new Apartment (" Warszawa ",55.25,100.15);

        LinkedList<Apartment> citylist = new LinkedList<Apartment>();
        citylist.add(kraków);
        citylist.add(warszawa);
        citylist.add(honkong);

        for(Apartment apartment:citylist){
            apartment.getFullPrice();
            apartment.average();
        }

        System.out.println("Average price : ");
    }
}
```

My expected:

```
1 : Apartment in   Krakow  cost 237,61
2 : Apartment in   Warszawa  cost 95,14
3 : Apartment in   Hongkong  cost 7600,11
Average price :.......??
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to calculate the average of `rabat` of all `apartments`?

Comment: Yes exactly. Average rabat for Honkong,Warszawa and Kraków.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would recommend to refactor your `Apartment` class. You should initialize all fields in the constructor so you don't have to call any methods to calculate the results:

```
public Apartment(String city, double area, double price) {
    this.city = city;
    this.area = area;
    this.price = price;
    this.rabat = price * multiplier;
}
```

Now to calculate the average `rabat` for all elements of your list you should add a getter for `rabat`. You then can use Java Streams like that:

```
double average = citylist.stream()
        .mapToDouble(Apartment::getRabat)
        .average()
        .orElse(-1);

System.out.println("Average price : " + average);
```

You create a `DoubleStream` with all values from the list. After that you can use the predefined `average()` method from `DoubleStream`. If your list is empty the number from `.orElse()` is returned.

Comment: Thank you for resolve my problem. I hope that my adventure with java will be pleasant and  I don't give up.